# ¿Cómo comprobar la existencia de un registro ingresado por JTextField en base de datos?

Tags: java, mysql

Tengo una consulta la cual me da todos los bastidores, al rellenar un formulario y pulsar "OK" compruebo si el bastidor introducido en `textfield_bastidor` existe en la `BBDD` y si no existe realizo la inserción, sino muestro un mensaje en pantalla de que ya existe e inserte otro.

¿Se podría comprobar una vez estoy tecleando en el mismo campo... es decir, haber la comprobación antes de enviar el formulario, por ejemplo al salirme del `focus() del jTextField` cambiando de color el textfield en caso de que fuera correcto o incorrecto?

Código de la consulta:

```
public static ArrayList cargar_bastidores() {
        ArrayList<String> bastidores = new ArrayList<String>();
        String bd = Conexiones.bbdd;
        Connection c = (Connection) Conexiones.conexion_a_BBDD(bd);
        Statement stm;
        ResultSet rs;
        try {
            //Consulta para sacar todos los bastidores de la tabla vehiculos.
            stm = c.createStatement();
            String consulta_bastidores = "SELECT bastidor FROM vehiculos ORDER BY bastidor ASC";
            rs = stm.executeQuery(consulta_bastidores);
            //System.out.println("CONSULTA TODOS LOS BASTIDORES: Mostramos todos los bastidores.");
            int i = 0;
            while (rs.next()) {
                String bastidor = rs.getString("bastidor");
                bastidores.add(bastidor);
                i++;
            }
            //System.out.println(bastidores);
            c.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            //e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Ha habido un error.");
        }     
        return bastidores;
    }
```

Código del formulario:

```
//Comprobamos si el bastidor no existe en la base de datos...
        if(!Conexiones.cargar_bastidores().contains(textfield_bastidor.getText())){
            //Depende de qué radiobutton pulsemos...
            if(radiobutton_alquiler.isSelected()){
                //Excepción por si el valor introducido no es un double.
                double precio = 0.0;
                try{
                    precio = Double.parseDouble(textfield_precio.getText());
                }catch(NumberFormatException nfe_precio){
                    nfe_precio.getMessage();
                }
                boolean disponible = checkbox_disponible.isSelected();
                Vehiculo va = new Vehiculo_Alquiler(precio, true, bastidor, color, matricula, modelo, 
                                                    marca, potencia, consumo, f, descripcion);
                //Llamamos al método alta_vehiculo() para insertar el vehículo en la base de datos.
                Conexiones.alta_vehiculo(va);
            }else{
                //Excepción por si el valor introducido no es un double.
                double precio = 0.0;
                try{
                    precio = Double.parseDouble(textfield_precio.getText());
                }catch(NumberFormatException nfe_precio){
                    nfe_precio.getMessage();
                }
                Vehiculo vc = new Vehiculo_Compra(precio, null, bastidor, color, matricula, modelo, 
                                                  marca, potencia, consumo, f, descripcion);
                //Llamamos al método alta_vehiculo() para insertar el vehículo en la base de datos.
                Conexiones.alta_vehiculo(vc);
            }
        }else{
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "¡¡¡Este bastidor EXISTE en la base de datos!!!");
            textfield_bastidor.requestFocus();
        }
```

Comment: Usa un evento `OnChange` o un evento `OnFocusLost`

Comment: @lois6b no encuentro ningún evento `OnFocusLost` ni `OnChange` en la documentación oficial. Posiblemente te refieras a `processFocusEvent`.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza tiré de memoria y me falló xD mezclé lenguajes seguro hahah

Comment: @lois6b eso imaginé pero el concepto es similar

Answer (score 0):

Una manera de realizar esto es utilizando el método **addFocusListener** con que cuenta la clase JTextField.

Este método recibe una instancia de una clase que implemente la interfaz **FocusListener**. Para lo que deseas hacer se pude generar una clase anónima de **FocusAdapter** (FocusAdapter es una clase que implementa la interfaz FocusListener) y sobreescribir el método focusLost que es el que se disparará cuando se pierda el foco de la caja de texto.

Te pongo el siguiente ejemplo, la primer caja de texto es la que escucha la perdida del foco:

```
public class Test {


    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JPanel panel = (JPanel)frame.getContentPane();
        panel.setLayout( new GridLayout(4, 1));
        final JTextField jTextField = new JTextField();
        final JLabel label = new JLabel("Texto");
        jTextField.addFocusListener( new FocusAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
                System.out.println("Haz perido el foco y tienes en el campo de texto "+jTextField.getText());
                label.setText("Haz escrito: "+jTextField.getText());
            }
        });

        panel.add(jTextField);
        panel.add(label);
        panel.add(new JTextField());
        panel.add(new JTextField());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hola amigo para para  lograr tu objetivo puedes usar al Evento FocusLost  en tu `textfield_bastidor`. Aqui te dejo este código para que lo ensayes

```
        textfield_bastidor.addFocusListener(new java.awt.event.FocusAdapter() {
        public void focusLost(java.awt.event.FocusEvent evt) {
            if(Conexiones.cargar_bastidores().contains(textfield_bastidor.getText())){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "El bastior ya se encuentra registrado en la base de datos","Duplicado",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                return;
            
            }
        }
    });
```

Si estas usadndo el IDE Netbeans para hacer tu interfaz gráfica puedes activar el evento de la siguiente manera:

1. Click derecho sobre el jtextfield_bastidor
2. Selecciona Events
3. De la lista que se despliega selecciona Focus
4. A continuación selecciona focusLost y automaticamente Netbeans te lleva a la línea donde debes ingresar tu código para validar si el bastidor se encuentra registrado en la base de datos.

Espero haberte ayudado